# How to run aiohttp app on pythonanywhere using aiohttp-wsgi library?

Tags: python, wsgi, aiohttp, pythonanywhere

Pythonanywhere uses wsgi server to run web apps. Aiohttp is async framework, which is not compatible with wsgi and pythonanywhere. But there is an aiohttp-wsgi lib which allows to run aiohttp with sync server by sacrificing it async advantages. Is it possible to use aiohttp-wsgi as glue between pythonanywhere and aiohttp app? The app is big enough so it will be hard to rewrite it in Django, for example. Async io does not matter for me for now.

I tried to write following to pythonanywhere wsgi config file:

```
import sys

path = '/home/TradingBotTest/'

if path not in sys.path:

    sys.path.append(path)

from aiohttp import web

from aiohttp_wsgi import WSGIHandler

from aiohttp.web import Request

from main import app

application = WSGIHandler(app)
```

But i get error:TypeError: WSGIHandler.handle_request() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
How to pass into WSGIHandler proper arguments?
Also i tried to wirite function:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
```

Which is also used to process request, bit how to properly call WSGIHandler call method with it arguments?

Comment: That most likely will not work on PA right now as all web apps are effectively being run by wsgi, while `aiohttp-wsgi` still assumes an aiohttp server running the app, if I understand correctly.